# C++ vector<vector<int> > reserve size at beginning

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

in c++ I have

```
vector<vector<int> > table;
```

How can I resize vector so that it has 3 rows and 4 columns, all zeros?

Something like that:

0000
0000
0000

So that I could later change for example

```
table[1][2] = 50;
```

I know i can do this with for loop, but is there other way?

In 1 dimensional vector I could have:

```
vector<int> myvector(5);
```

And i could then type for example:

```
myvector[3]=50;
```

So, my question is how to do it with 2 dimensional, or even multidimensional vector?

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried to answer this (and obviously others have too) but it's really unclear. Reserve or resize? "how to do it" do _what_? _I_ can see that you're asking how to pass initial size at construction for nested vectors, but in order for this to remain a good part of the SO Q&A repository it ought to be tidied up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an explicit default value to the constructor:

```
vector<string> example(100, "example");  
vector<vector<int>> table (3, vector<int>(4));
vector<vector<vector<int>>> notveryreadable (3, vector<vector<int>>(4, vector<int> (5, 999)));
```

The last one is more readable if it's built "piecewise":

```
vector<int> dimension1(5, 999);
vector<vector<int>> dimension2(4, dimension1);
vector<vector<vector<int>>> dimension3(3, dimension2);
```

particularly if you use explicit `std::` - code that looks like

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>> lol(3, std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>(4, std::vector<std::string> (5, "lol")));
```

should be reserved for bad jokes.

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<vector<int> > table(3, vector<int>(4,0));
```

This creates a vector with 3 rows and 4 columns all initialized
 to 0

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[resize()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/)** from std::vector :

```
 table.resize(4);                           // resize the columns
 for (auto &row : table) { row.resize(3); } // resize the rows
```

Or you can directly initialize it as :

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> table(4,std::vector<int>(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't! You'll have complex code and rubbish memory locality.

Instead have a vector of twelve integers, wrapped by a class that converts 2D indices into 1D indices.

```
template<typename T>
struct matrix
{
   matrix(unsigned m, unsigned n)
     : m(m)
     , n(n)
     , vs(m*n)
   {}

   T& operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j)
   {
      return vs[i + m * j];
   }

private:
   unsigned m;
   unsigned n;
   std::vector<T> vs;
};

int main()
{
   matrix<int> m(3, 4);   // <-- there's your initialisation
   m(1, 1) = 3;
}
```