# C++ subprogram vector<vector<short> > pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have basically a cube with numbers 1-6 (for monopoly for example) stored in

```
vector<vector<short> > cube;
```

it looks like this:

```
0300
5126
0400
```

I have code for rotating it upside:

```
short tmp=cube[0][1];
cube[0][1]=cube[1][1];
cube[1][1]=cube[2][1];
cube[2][1]=tmp;
```

My question is how can i create function from that code with **pointers** or something simmilar so I dont have to copy that vector to function, but just change existing vector? Something like:

```
void rotateCubeUp(vector<vector<short> >cube){
    short tmp=cube[0][1];
    cube[0][1]=cube[1][1];
    cube[1][1]=cube[2][1];
    cube[2][1]=tmp;
}
```

But this is without pointers.

Comment: Pass the vector by reference, not by value.

Comment: `vector<vector<short>>` does not seem like  a sane representation for a die. A standard die is represented entirely by whether it's left- or right-handed, and by, say, which side faces up and which side faces the front. Basically that's only 60 configurations in total; and rotations could be stored as permutations of those.

Comment: Repeating [my prior advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28087605/560648): drop this nested vector business.

Comment: I think that the reason that there are "unfolded cube" questions on IQ tests is that it's a lousy representation.

Comment: I know task can be solved easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the vector by reference. Reference is just an alias. Please read about reference and when to use it in detail. It is very useful concept in C++.

```
void rotateCubeUp( vector< vector<short> >& cube){
    short tmp=cube[0][1];
    cube[0][1]=cube[1][1];
    cube[1][1]=cube[2][1];
    cube[2][1]=tmp;
}
```

Suggestion: Use "at" instead of "[]" while accessing vector elements. [] does not provide index checking.